# On page refresh I get this error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, components, state

My app is working fine and I can refresh other pages. But when I refresh the page where an event is being edited (EditEvent Component) it gives me this error message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name'). And I've noticed that all my state variables are "undefined" after the refresh, even at the top level(App.js). Can someone please help?

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Routes,  Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import SignUp from "./components/SignUp";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import EditEvent from "./components/EditEvent";
import NewEvent from "./components/NewEvent";



function App() {

  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState("");
  const [events, setEvents] = useState([])
  const [clients, setClients] = useState([])
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/auth')
    .then(r => {
      if(r.ok){
        r.json().then(user => {
          setCurrentUser(user)
          setClients(user.clients)
        }
          )
      }
    })
  },[])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/events')
    .then(r => {
      if(r.ok){
        r.json().then(events => setEvents(events)
          )
      }
    })
  },[])



  function handleLogin(user) {
    setCurrentUser(user)
  }

  function handleSetUser(user) {
    setCurrentUser(user)
  }

  function handleEditEvent(editedEvent) {
    const unchangedEvents = events.filter(event => event.id !== editedEvent.id)
    setEvents([...unchangedEvents,editedEvent])

  }

  function handleDeleteEvent(deletedEvent){
    const updatedEvents = events.filter((event) => event.id !== deletedEvent.id)
    setEvents([...updatedEvents])
  }

  function handleNewEvent(newEvent) {
    setEvents([...events,newEvent])
  }

  console.log(events)
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/home" element ={<Home currentUser={currentUser} setCurrentUser={setCurrentUser} events={events} clients={clients} onEventDelete={handleDeleteEvent} addEvent={handleNewEvent}/>} />
        <Route path="/" element={<Login onLogin={handleLogin}/>} />
        <Route path="/signup" element={<SignUp setUser={handleSetUser}/>} />
        <Route path="/events/:id" element={<EditEvent events={events} clients={clients} onEditEvent={handleEditEvent} />} />
        <Route path="/newevent" element={<NewEvent events={events} clients={clients} addEvent={handleNewEvent}/>} />
      </Routes>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Home.js

```
import React from 'react';
import NavBar from './NavBar';
import Events from './Events';
import Vendors from './Vendors';
import { useState } from "react"
import NewEvent from './NewEvent';

function Home({ currentUser, setCurrentUser, events, clients, onEventDelete, addEvent }) {

    const [active, setActive] = useState('Events')

    return (


        <div>
            <NavBar currentUser={currentUser} setCurrentUser={setCurrentUser} setActive = {setActive}/>
            {active === "Events" && <Events events={events} clients={clients} onEventDelete={onEventDelete} />}
            {active === "Vendors" && <Vendors />}
            {active === "NewEvent" && <NewEvent clients={clients} addEvent={addEvent} currentUser={currentUser} setActive={'Events'}/>}
        </div>


    );
}

export default Home;
```

Events.js

```
import React from "react";
import EventCard from "./EventCard";
import "../Container.css";

function Events ( { events, onEventDelete } ) {

  const renderEvents = events.sort( (a,b) => a.id > b.id ? 1 : -1).map((event) => ( <EventCard key={event.id} event={event} onEventDelete={onEventDelete}/> ))

    return (
        <section className="twitter">
        <h1 className="header">Upcoming Events</h1>
        <div className="container">
          {renderEvents}
        </div>
      </section>
    )

}

export default Events;
```

EventCard.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import "../Container.css";

function EventCard( { event, onEventDelete }) {

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    function handleEventDelete() {
        fetch(`/events/${event.id}`, {
            method: 'DELETE'
        })
        .then(()=> {
            onEventDelete(event)
        });
    }

    function getTime(eventTime) {

        const time = eventTime.split('T')[1];
        const hour = time.split(':')[0];
        const minutes = time.split(':')[1];
        let timeValue = '';
        if (hour > 0 && hour <= 12) {
            timeValue= "" + hour
          } else if (hour > 12) {
            timeValue= "" + (hour - 12);
          } else if (hour === 0) {
            timeValue= "12"
          }

        const standardTime = timeValue + ':' + minutes;
        const dayNight =  timeValue = (hour >= 12) ? " P.M." : " A.M.";

        return standardTime + dayNight;

    }

    function handleEdit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        navigate(`/events/${event.id}`)
    }

    return ( <div className='card' >
         <h1 className='title'>{event.name}</h1>
             <p>Client: {event.client.name}</p>
             <p>Date: {event.start_date}</p>
             <p>Time: {getTime(event.start_time)}</p>
             <p>Location: {event.location}</p>
             <p>Description: {event.description}</p>
             <br></br>
             <ul>
                Vendors:
                {event.vendors.map((vendor) => 
                <li key={vendor.id}>{vendor.name}</li>)}
             </ul>

                 <button id='edit-button' onClick={handleEdit} >Edit</button >
             <button id='delete-button' onClick={handleEventDelete}>Delete Event</button>
       </div>) 
     

 
    
}

export default EventCard;
```

EditEvent.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from "react";
import { Link, useNavigate, useParams} from "react-router-dom";
import "../index.css"


function EditEvent ( { events, onEditEvent, clients } ) {
    

    const params = useParams();
    const event = events.find((event) => event.id == params.id)
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    


   
    const [name, setName] = useState(event.name);
    const [description, setDescription] = useState(event.description);
    const [location, setLocation] = useState(event.location);
    const [budget, setBudget] = useState(event.budget);
    const [currentCost, setCurrentCost] = useState(event.current_cost);
    const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(event.start_date);
    const [startTime, setStartTime] = useState(getTime(event.start_time));
    const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(event.end_date);
    const [endTime, setEndTime] = useState(event.end_time);
    const [selectedClient, setSelectedClient] = useState(event.client.name)

    function getTime(eventTime) {

        const time = eventTime.split('T')[1];
        const hour = time.split(':')[0];
        const minutes = time.split(':')[1];
        let timeValue = '';
        if (hour > 0 && hour <= 12) {
            timeValue= "" + hour
          } else if (hour > 12) {
            timeValue= "" + (hour - 12);
          } else if (hour == 0) {
            timeValue= "12"
          }

        const standardTime = timeValue + ':' + minutes;
        const dayNight =  timeValue = (hour >= 12) ? " P.M." : " A.M.";

        return standardTime + dayNight;

    }

    function handleClientChange(e) {
        setSelectedClient(e.target.value)
   }

    function handleSubmitChanges(e) {
        e.preventDefault()

        const client = clients.find((client) => client.name == selectedClient)

        const editedEvent = {
            name: name,
            description: description,
            start_date: startDate,
            start_time: startTime,
            end_date: endDate,
            end_time: endTime,
            locaiton: location,
            budget: budget,
            current_cost: currentCost,
            id: event.id,
            client_id: client.id,
        }


        fetch(`/events/${editedEvent.id}`, {
            method: 'PATCH',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(editedEvent)
        })
        .then(r => r.json())
        .then(editedEvent => {
            onEditEvent(editedEvent)
            navigate("/home")
        })
        

    }


    console.log(selectedClient)

  return event ? (

        <div className='edit-background'>
         <form className="edit-form" onSubmit={handleSubmitChanges}>
             <div className="edit-title">Edit Event</div>
             <div className="input-container ic0">
                <input  id="name" className="input" type="text"  defaultValue={name}  onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}/>
                <label className="edit-cut edit-cut-short">Name</label>
            </div>
            <div className="input-container ic0">
                <input id="desc" className="input" type="text" defaultValue={description} onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}/>
                <label className="edit-cut edit-cut-short">Description</label>
            </div>
            <div className="input-container ic0">
                <input id="start-date" className="input" type="text" defaultValue={startDate} onChange={(e) => setStartDate(e.target.value)}/>
                <label className="edit-cut edit-cut-short">Start Date</label>
            </div>
            <div className="input-container ic0">
                 <input id="start-time" className="input" type="text" defaultValue={startTime}  onChange={(e) => setStartTime(e.target.value)}/>
                <label className="edit-cut edit-cut-short">Start Time</label>
            </div>
            <div className="input-container ic0">
                <input id="end-date" className="input" type="text" defaultValue={endDate} onChange={(e) => setEndDate(e.target.value)}/>
                <label className="edit-cut edit-cut-short">End Date</label>
            </div>
            <div className="input-container ic0">
                 <input id="end-time" className="input" type="text" defaultValue={endTime} onChange={(e) => setEndTime(e.target.value)}/>
                <label className="edit-cut edit-cut-short">End Time</label>
            </div>
            <div className="input-container ic0">
                <input id="location" className="input" type="text" defaultValue={location} onChange={(e) => setLocation(e.target.value)}/>
                <label className="edit-cut edit-cut-short">Location</label>
            </div>
            <div className="input-container ic0">
                <input id="budget" className="input" type="text" defaultValue={budget} onChange={(e) => setBudget(e.target.value)}/>
                <label className="edit-cut edit-cut-short">Budget</label>
            </div>
            <div className="input-container ic0">
                <input id="current-cost" className="input" type="integer"  defaultValue={currentCost} onChange={(e) => setCurrentCost(e.target.value)}/>
                <label className="edit-cut edit-cut-short">Current Cost</label>
            </div>
            <select value={selectedClient} onChange={handleClientChange}>
                {clients.map((client) => <option key={client.id}>{client.name}</option>)}
            </select>
            <button type="submit" className="submit">Edit</button>
            <Link to={"/home"}>
                <button id='submit'>Cancel</button >
            </ Link>
         </form>
        </div>
        
    ) : null
};

export default EditEvent;
```

NavBar.js

```
import React from "react";
import "../NavBar.css";
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function NavBar( {currentUser, setCurrentUser, setActive } ) {

    const navigate = useNavigate()

    function handleLogOut() {
        navigate('/')
        fetch('/logout',{method: "DELETE"}).then((r) => {
            if(r.ok){
                setCurrentUser(null)
            }
        })
    };

return (
<main className="main">
  <aside className="sidebar">
    <p className="greeting">Hello {currentUser.first_name}</p>
    <nav className="nav">
        <button className="nav-button" onClick={() => setActive("NewEvent")}>New Event</button>
        <button className="nav-button" onClick={() => setActive("Events")}>Events</button>
        <button className="nav-button" onClick={() => setActive("Vendors")}>Vendors</button>
        <button className="nav-button" onClick={handleLogOut}>Logout</button>
    </nav>

  </aside>
</main>
)

}

export default NavBar;
```

Comment: React state resides in memory. Unless you are persisting it to localStorage or similar and repopulating the state, it will be lost upon a page reload. *Where* exactly in the code is the error being produced? Some/which `***.name` is trying to be read? Is there a code stacktrace to go with the error? My hunch is that it's in the `EditEvent` component when setting the initial `const [name, setName] = useState(event.name);` state.

Comment: @DrewReese, yes initially when I render the EditEvent component the events variable shows an array of events but when I refresh it, it shows undefined

Answer (score 0):

In your code snippets all the places where any `name` property is accessed is in an `Array.prototype.map` callback, which should be safe when the array is empty, except one place in the `EditEvent` component where the `events` prop is searched by an event id.

`Array.prototype.find` returns undefined if no element in the array matches.

`EditEvent` should check that an `event` was actually found prior to accessing into the result.

Example:

```
function EditEvent ( { events, onEditEvent, clients } ) {
    const { id } = useParams();
    const event = events.find((event) => String(event.id) === id);
    const navigate = useNavigate();
   
    const [name, setName] = useState(event?.name ?? "");
    const [description, setDescription] = useState(event?.description ?? "");
    const [location, setLocation] = useState(event?.location ?? "");
    ... etc
```

The above uses the Optional Chaining operator and Nullish Coalescing to set the initial state to the event property or an empty string in the case `event[x]` is null or undefined.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! @Drew Reese. It doesn't give me the error anymore. It does clear my default values but I think I should be ok for this school project lol. Thanks again!

Comment: @angiem103 I don't know quite what you mean by "default values", but if you need to "react" to the `events` prop being updated while `EditEvent` is being rendered then you can use a `useEffect` hook with a dependency on the `events` array to issue a side-effect to update/reset the local component state.